# how to convert byte array to excel file in spring boot

Tags: java, arrays, excel, spring, jxl

I want to create an excel file from byte[]. and I'm using `jxl` library in spring boot.
I need a file with `XLS` format, convert to Base64 and return that.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(20000000);
WritableWorkbook workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(outputStream);

...

String resultBase64 = reportService.fetchReportExcel(...);
byte[] excel = base64.decode( resultBase64 );
```

I have many byte arrays and I need to write btye arrays in many sheets of an excel file too, if it's possible.
thanks

Comment: What do they byte arrays contain and in what way do you want to convert them to excel?

Comment: Hi, thanks. Each byte array is an excel file. I get they from a rest api, they're xls files. I can get they with foreach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I write it

my code:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(20000000);

String resultBase64 = reportApplicationService.fetchReportExcel(...);
byte[] excel = base64.decode( resultBase64 );

outputStream.write(excel);
outputStream.flush();

response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=name.xls");
response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
response.setContentLength((int) outputStream.size());
StreamUtils.copy(new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray()), response.getOutputStream());
```